# What would be a good way to split a controller into multiple files in NestJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs

I have a NestJs project which for the purpose of the project has multiple services for different providers but needs to have one controller which depending on the parameters will call the relevant provider service as each of the providers will have different implementations of similar functions.

Is it possible to split the controller into multiple files which are all included into the controller.

If so would this be best practice or is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Feel like you can get an advantage using the strategy pattern when implementing the service. https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/strategy